# EF code first make one to many relationship

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have 2 models, Task and Offer:

```
  public class Task
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int id { get; set; }
       [Key]
        public Guid TaskId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Offer> Offers { get; set; }

    }

    public class Offer
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public Guid OfferId { get; set; }
        public Guid TaskId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("TaskId")]
        public virtual Task Task { get; set; }


    }
```

A task can have many offers, and 1 offer have one tasks, i thought it shopuld be pretty straight forward, but i ran into different troubles, after googling for couple of hours i found out that i have to use fluent mapping, which i did:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Offer>().HasRequired(p => p.Task).WithMany(c => c.Offers).HasForeignKey(e=>e.TaskId2).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

but now i cant get rid of this error:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.Offers_dbo.Tasks_TaskId". The conflict occurred in database
>   "test", table "dbo.Tasks", column 'TaskId'

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I agree you should not need the fluent api to do a plain one to many. What do you mean by "i ran into different troubles" with the dataannotations configuration? Also, what is TaskId2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not necessarily need any settings through Fluent API.

You should be good by deleting the following code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Offer>().HasRequired(p => p.Task).WithMany(c => c.Offers).HasForeignKey(e=>e.TaskId2).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

And changing your `Task` entity as follows:

```
public class Task{
    private ICollection<Offer> _offers;
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public Guid TaskId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Offer> Offers {
        get { return _offers = _offers ?? new HashSet<Offer>(); }
        set { _offers = value; }
    }
}
```

And also, you need to delete `public Guid TaskId { get; set; }` and `public int id { get; set; }` from `Offer` entity. Any property that has `id` word on it will be treated as key for the table.

Comment: It got me futher, now i get this error:  Multiple identity columns specified for table 'Offers'. Only one identity column per table is allowed. As far as i understood from googling, on my Offers tabel  auto generation is trying to set both TaskId and OfferId as primary keys. how to get around it?

Comment: based on the EF conversions, any `Property` that includes the letter `id` will be treated as a key for the table. So remove `public int id` or `public Guid TaskId`. Sorry for missing this in my answer, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: If i remove taskId from offers how do i select offers based on specific task id? thats the only thing i am missing now.

Comment: `one-to-many` relationship will insert a column called `TaskId_Task` in your `Offer` table. You will be able to select like this: `var offers = context.Offer.Where(x => x.Task.TaskId=taskid);`

Comment: Oh, so i actullay dont have to set it manually... lol! Thank you very much, was struggeling with this problem for two days now !